# Showing Number of Comments without the Link

Tags: wordpress

When I use `<?php comments_number('0', '1', '%'); ?>` this code, that come with span HTML code. I need to show number of comments on `a` tag's `title` attribute. So how can I?

```
<div class="comment">
    <a href="#" title="<?php comments_number('0', '1', '%'); ?>"></a>
</div>
```

[this is how is it looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqo22.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the numeric value using [`get_comments_number()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number):

```
<div class="comment">
    <a href="#" title="<?php echo get_comments_number(); ?>"></a>
</div>
```